# How to count numbers between 2 numbers L and R (both included) such that product of the digits of the selected numbers is even?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to find the count of numbers between 2 numbers L and R (both included) which have product of their digits even?
How can we go about it other than brute force?

```
dp[0][0]=4;
dp[0][1]=5;
for(int l=1;l<=9;l++)
{
    dp[l][0]=0;
    dp[l][1]=0;
    dp[l][0]+=(dp[l-1][0])*10;
    dp[l][0]+=dp[l-1][1]*5;
    dp[l][1]+=dp[l-1][1]*5;          
}
```

Here is a brute force checker I had made,I am trying to develop a more efficient solution

```
bool f(ll n)
{
  ll p=1;
  if(n==0)
  return true;
  while(n)
  {
     p*=n%10;
     n/=10;
     if(p%2==0) return true;
     p=1;
  }
  if(p%2) return false;
  else
  return true;
}
ll brute(ll l,ll r)
{
   if(l>r) swap(l,r);
    ll cnt=0;
   for(ll  i=l;i<=r;i++)
   {
      if(f(i))
      {
         cnt++;
      }
   }

return cnt;
```

}

`dp[l-1][0]` stores count of even product numbers of length l 
That is what I had thought..?
Can this solve the problem
?

Comment: Did you think of something?

Comment: If the product is even that just means that at least one of then is even

Comment: There's a `log10(R)` solution, but I don't think it's necessary for you.

Comment: @ipc:I would love  to learn what is the log10(R) solution

Comment: It is much easier to figure out which numbers have an odd product of digits.  Then you just need to do a subtraction.

Comment: @aschepler:How can this be done in logarithmic time?

Comment: @ipc:perhaps you just wanted to insult me by adding that comment

Comment: i think there is a non-brute force way and it is indeed logarithmic

Comment: @AndyProwl:go on,suggest it

Comment: @user1907531: working on it

Comment: The title asks for `product of the selected numbers is even` while the question asks for `product of their digits even?` Which one is it?

Comment: @amit:It is strange that you only read the title

Comment: Seems I completely misunderstood the question ..

Answer (score 3):

Brute force is a terribly wasteful approach.  We can do much better.

(I apologize for the formatting; I hope the content is still clear enough.)

### First, let's simplify the problem:

```
EvenProductNumbersBetween(RangeStart, RangeEnd) = NumbersBetween(RangeEnd - RangeStart) - AllOddDigitNumbersBetween(RangeStart, RangeEnd)

NumbersBetween(RangeStart, RangeEnd) = (RangeEnd - RangeStart) + 1

AllOddDigitNumbersBetween(RangeStart, RangeEnd) = AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeEnd) - AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeStart-1)
```

### Now we get to the meat: calculating AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeEnd)

**First, consider the simple cases:**

(Assume RangeEnd is positive)

*If RangeEnd is a single digit (i.e. < 10), then*

```
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeEnd) = Floor((RangeEnd+1)/2)

E.g.:
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(0) = {} = 0
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(1) = {1} = 1
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(2) = {1} = 1
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(3) = {1,3} = 2
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(4) = {1,3} = 2
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(5) = {1,3,5} = 3
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(6) = {1,3,5} = 3
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(7) = {1,3,5,7} = 4
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(8) = {1,3,5,7} = 4
AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(9) = {1,3,5,7,9} = 5
```

*If RangeEnd can be any number with a specific number of digits, then*

Consider that each digit must have one of the five odd numbers as choices (leading zeroes shorten the length, and are thus excluded), so this is trivial to calculate, directly:

```
AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(NumberLength) = 5^NumberLength

E.g.:
AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(1) = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} = 5
AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(2) = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} * {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} = 5*5 = 25
AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(3) = 5*5*5 = 125
...
```

**Otherwise, break RangeEnd apart:**

```
RangeEnd = (FirstDigit * 10^PowerOfFirstDigit) + Remainder

AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeEnd) = AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(FirstDigit) * AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(PowerOfFirstDigit-1) + AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(Remainder)
```

Unfortunately, there's a complicating case with leading zeroes.  (Thanks to @AndyProwl for pointing me toward this problem with an earlier version of my answer!)  If Remainder starts with a zero, then we *should NOT* add the AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(Remainder) term, at the end, because the constrained leading zero would make the product even for every smaller number we would try to make.

```
E.g.:

AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(6300193) =
= AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(6*(10^7) + 300193)
= AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(6) * AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(7-1) + AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(300193)
= 3 * 5^6 + AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(300193)
= Trivial * Trivial + LogarithmicallySmallerCase

AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(300193) =
= AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(3*(10^6) + 00193)
= AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(3) * AllOddDigitNumbersOfLength(6-1)
= 2 * 5^5
= Trivial * Trivial
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, shouldn't `AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(100)` include `AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(10)`? Or you mean only the numbers with exactly 2 digits?

Comment: @AndyProwl: You're right!  I'm conflating the two things, in that case.  I'll fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: I am still not sure if the decomposition `AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(RangeEnd) = AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(FirstDigit) * AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(PowerOfFirstDigit) + AllOddDigitNumbersUpTo(Remainder)` is correct, but I upvoted anyway because of the idea of inverting the problem: I focused on finding all sequences with at least one even digit, while it's way more clever to search for those with all odd digits

Comment: @AndyProwl: Thanks, Andy!  I had not properly handled leading zeroes, but I think I've fixed the issues, now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably have to inspect each number the minimal time is linear O(n) so I would go by brute force since I don't think there is an algorithm for it.

Comment: :I want a more efficient algorithm

Comment: Why would you need to inspect every number? You can exploit the fact that the product is even if and only if at least one of the numbers in it is even.

Comment: but you still need to inspect them for that (?)

Comment: The range `[L,R]` is `L,L+1,...,R-1,R`